# Why Git don't add folder?

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to add folder `app/static/icon` in repo.

When i make `git add app/static/icon`, Git return:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
app/static/icon
Use -f if you really want to add them.
```

My .gitignore file:

```
**/__pycache__/
**/*.pyc
.idea/

params.py

flask/

app/static/load/
db/
```

Why this folder ignored?

Comment: are there any nested gitignore files?

Comment: Use `git check-ignore -v app/static/icon` to find out.

Comment: no nested gitignore

Comment: /Users/kosyachniy/.config/git/ignore:9:Icon app/static/icon

Comment: There is your answer:you seem to have a global ignore for this path!

Comment: git doesn't work with directories, only with files, so it doesn't even matter that it's in an ignore file.  (It doesn't work with "folders" either, whatever that means)

Comment: If this was caused by Git not adding empty folders, it would just silently add nothing. The error message is important and @GhostCat pointed out correctly that the global config is ignoring this folder in this case. @kosyachniy: you can simply use `git add -f`, as the message says, or change your global configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git check-ignore -v app/static/icon` to find out.